# how to use ng-class in ng-repeat to set class for each itrative div's

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

- **this is my home page ** i am showing data coming from mysql to card but is have same tag color i.e class="tag tag-pill tag-danger"
  i am using ng-class={{hos.class}} /*class is a coloumn in table */

  ```
  <div class="col-md-5" ng-repeat="hos in ho">
       <div class="col-md-6">
           <div class="card"> <img class="img-fluid" ng-src="{{hos.img}}" alt="">
                <div class="card-img-overlay"> <span ng-class=" ">{{hos.tag}}</span> </div>
                <div class="card-block">
  <div class="news-title">
  <h2 class=" title-small"><a href="#">{{hos.topic}}</a></h2>
  </div>
  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-time"><em>{{hos.time}}</em></small></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ng-class="hos.tag"` or `class="{{hos.tag}}"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using ng-class incorrectly: its expression comprises of an object where each property is a class and the value is an expression to evaluate to conditionally apply that class when truth.

For example `ng-class="{'active': button.active}"`

Hopefully, this fiddle will help: [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/p66mv6tn/1/)